# Upon creation of new user non-existent groups added

Tags: linux, user-management

I am little puzzled with below outcome. I am logged in as root and created 2 new user. tecmint and tecmint2. New user became part of group that I cant find in /etc/group. How can I find out why this is happening and fix it. User added using below command.

```
root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # useradd -G ldap tecmint2
```

The GID 55 is `ldap` but it shows as `dba` when I list user using `id` command

```
root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # cat /etc/group | grep 100
users:x:100:
tecmint:x:1000:
tecmint2:x:1001:
root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # cat /etc/group | grep 55
ldap:x:55:tecmint,tecmint2
root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # id -a tecmint2
uid=1001(tecmint2) gid=1001(jbase5) groups=1001(jbase5),55(dba)
root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # id -a tecmint
uid=1000(tecmint) gid=1000(tibco) groups=1000(tibco),55(dba)
```

Any clue on this would be really helpful :)

Thanks, Dwija.

Added a few more lines on searching group name from files under /etc

`root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'tecmint' /etc/group:63:ldap:x:55:tecmint,tecmint2 /etc/group:64:tecmint:x:1000: /etc/gshadow:63:ldap:!::tecmint,tecmint2 /etc/gshadow:64:tecmint:!:: /etc/passwd:38:tecmint:x:1000:1000::/home/tecmint:/bin/bash /etc/group-:63:ldap:x:55:tecmint /etc/group-:64:tecmint:x:1000: /etc/gshadow-:63:ldap:!::tecmint /etc/gshadow-:64:tecmint:!:: /etc/shadow:38:tecmint:$6$DsZ1ssCj$GjgFqqrliSo5u6jxwfY /etc/subgid:1:tecmint:100000:65536 /etc/passwd-:38:tecmint:x:1000:1000::/home/tecmint:/bin/bash /etc/subuid:1:tecmint:100000:65536 /etc/shadow-:38:tecmint:$6$DsZ1ssCj$GjgFqqrliSo5u6jxwfYiG /etc/subgid-:1:tecmint:100000:65536 /etc/subuid-:1:tecmint:100000:65536 root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'jbase5'`

`root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'dba' Binary file /etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100/mandb/hll matches Binary file /etc/udev/hwdb.bin matches`

`root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'tibco'`

No result from any files under `/etc/` by searching above group name.

Comment: Look for `dba` in the `/etc/group` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Here is output grep. It seems the /etc/group is not correct place to refer for RHEL 7.x as the group not present there yet new user get tagged to. 

`infra1@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] $ cat /etc/group | grep dba`
`infra1@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] $`

Comment: Did you also check the `/etc/gshadow` file?

Comment: could add long comment. instead I updated the original post. I cant find those group name anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason is that on networked systems, groups may not only read from /etc/group file, but also obtained through LDAP or Yellow Pages (the list of known groups comes from the local group file plus groups received via LDAP or YP in these cases).
> If you want just the group names you can use:

> getent group | cut -d: -f1

Above from this page explains why I cant see group name in local server but ID's are assigned to.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059916/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-unix-group-names

`getent group` - I used this command to list of groups available and it showed the group that I was looking for.This test server is part of a LDAP network and group names were fetched from LDAP. so the mystery solved.

```
root@uklvadsb0047[DEV][~] # getent group | grep -e tibco -e jbase5 -e dba
asmdba:x:59:
dba:x:55:
jbase5:x:1001:
tibco:x:1000:
```

thank you @Michael for your replies. Next is to search how to prevent use group name from LDAP and use local group name.